# Is it possible to Get UVMap Attribute from object info node? (Geometry Nodes)

Tags: uv, instances, geometry-nodes, custom-attributes

I have created a point cloud map for a UV unwrapped plane which corresponds to a texture. The plane is being instanced on a curve then I am distributing points onto the instanced plane from within the Curve Node-group, I would then like to utilise the UV Data of the instanced object to influence the point distribution.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Could you share your blend file? It's not clear to me exactly how your nodes are structured and where you want to access which values.

Comment: Hi, I've included a blend file with the problem broken down. I've also made an edit to the question.

Comment: Next time don't forget to pack the resources when you share a blend file ;-)

Comment: I'm not really sure, if I understood, what you want to achieve. But if you want to have more control over the distribution of the points, you may use weight painting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, simply put, you want to use an image to influence the distribution of your points.

If this is the case, then you have the following options:

1. Distribute points on your surface
2. Measure the dimensions of the point distribution
3. Map the coordinates into a range from $0-1$ (your UVs start at $(0, 0)$ in the lower left corner and end at $(1, 1)$ in the upper right corner)
4. Use these positions as vector for your image texture and remove points from the cloud that match your rule

[image]

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.1+)*</sub>

Comment: Thanks! this was pretty much what I needed. I turned the scale back into a vector and also plugged a vector add after the position to get further control.

After reviewing, I guess my question was how to scale the UV map geo nodes side, rather than getting the UV map in the first place.